# How to I drag automatically copy/drag formula Horizontally with Vertical Data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to I drag automatically copy/drag formula Horizontally with Vertical Data?

I have attached a pic below for explanation.
Is it possible to do so when i drag or copy formular

[picture for clearer explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp3PE.png)

Answer (score 1):

*You need to use this Formula in Cell `B2` and drag towards Right.*

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-1,0)
```

**Note:**

- Edit the `Column()-1` according to the formula Cell position for the Column.
- For example if you write the Formula in Cell `C2` then your Formula should be written like this.

  `=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-2,0)`